# Laser shooting unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

help to implement shooting in Unity 2D. I need the enemy to shoot a laser that gradually increases the brightness as in many games. That is, when the enemy shoots, a red dim stripe appears (it does not have properties yet, just a stripe), then it becomes brighter and when it becomes completely bright, it becomes like a cartridge and deals damage. I just need to implement the gradual appearance of the strip.

Moon has no ideas at all

Comment: Looks like off-topic, beacause it's not about programming

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [line renderer](https://vionixstudio.com/2023/01/31/unity-line-renderer-ultimate-guide/) to make the strip appear. Control the thickness of the line renderer to make it gradually appear. Then you can use a [spherecast](https://vionixstudio.com/2023/02/14/unity-spherecast/) to the thickness of the line renderer to find objects hit by it and deal damage.